# Permissions denied but still the app can use it

Tags: permissions, android-11

[image: Screenshot of "App Permissions" and "All Permissions"]As you can see in the attachment, i have denied access to microphone. But when I go to "All Permissions", it shows that the app can still use microphone. What does that mean? And how can I stop it from using my microphone?

Comment: I guess that is info about what permissions that app **could** have (once you grant it) not actually what permissions granted. Why don't you test the microphone in chrome yourself (voice-to-text)?

Comment: You can take permission denial to a next level using [PMX](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX). Deny manifest permission as well as the related AppOp. Disclosure: I'm the author of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"All Permissions" just give an insight into what all permissions the app can have once allowed, i.e. it just shows that chrome has the ability to "record audio using the microphone at any time".